# SecurID authentication in a Linux C++ application

Tags: c++, pam, securid

Can anyone recommend how to implement SecurID authentication in Linux C++ based application? I I was thinking of the following options:

1. An apache module for SecurID (we're using Apache on the front-end)
2. PAM
3. Some combination of SecurID through Radius that I've heard about but don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Using something like [`ace-radius`](http://ace-radius.sourceforge.net/) together with a RADIUS server seems to me like the easiest solution.

If I recall right RSA provides a RADIUS server in the ACE/SecurID distribution, so this should be easy to setup.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, fastest way to integrate with SecurID is the SecurID apache module (http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-securid/rsa-authentication-agents/apache-7-1.htm).

Using the RSA SecurID PAM module (http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-securid/rsa-authentication-agents/pam-7-0.htm) is another option, that has the advantage that it'd also provide OS-level OS-level authentication.

The 3rd option would be to integrate RADIUS in your app and have it talk to Authentication Manger, but it's probably as simple if not simpler to use SecurID SDK directly (in C in your case) so that your app talks directly to the Authentication Manager server.

Hope this helps